# Are accessors of class properties useful?

Tags: encapsulation, accessor, gdscript

Consider the following accessor methods of the property `global_position` of the class [`Node2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/fr/stable/classes/class_node2d.html#class-node2d-property-global-position):

---

**Vector2 global_position**

- *Setter* `set_global_position(value)`
- *Getter* `get_global_position()`

---

But the property is not encapsulated as shown by this example:

```
tool

extends EditorScript

func _run() -> void:
    var n = Node2D.new()
    n.global_position = Vector2(100, 100)
    print(n.global_position)
```

which produces:

```
* scene/2d/canvas_item.cpp:467 - Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true. Returned: get_transform()
(100, 100)
```

Are those accessors useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are NOT useless. They are useful… If the node is in the scene tree.

*You can add the node to the scene tree with [`add_child`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-add-child) or [`add_child_below_node`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-add-child-below-node).*

---

I'm not sure what you mean by "not encapsulated". Just in case, I'll point out that you are NOT bypassing them.

When you use the property, you are using the getter and setter methdods. The property is a convenience for language binding. Thus, we could also say that you don't need the property, only the getter and setter.

You can see in the [source for `Node2D`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/2d/node_2d.cpp), that there is a `_bind_methods` function that sets all the properties and methods that are exposed to use. This is how `global_position` looks like:

```
ADD_PROPERTY(PropertyInfo(Variant::VECTOR2, "global_position", PROPERTY_HINT_NONE, "", 0), "set_global_position", "get_global_position");
```

---

That message you are getting is because you are using `global_position` on a node that is not on the scene tree. And, yes in that case, it is not useful. We can figure that out with a simple script:

```
extends Node2D

func _ready() -> void:
    global_position = Vector2(200, 300)
    var n = Node2D.new()
    n.global_position = Vector2(100, 100)
    print(n.global_position)
    add_child(n)
    print(n.global_position)
```

This outputs:

```
(100, 100)
(300, 400)
```

Thus, as you can see, it will have a different global position from what was set. And the difference depends on the position of the parent. Setting `position` would have the same effect. *Thus setting `global_position` not useful here.*

---

If you want to go deeper on what `global_position` does, we can have a look at the source of the getter and setter (part of the linked source for `Node2D`):

```
Point2 Node2D::get_global_position() const {

    return get_global_transform().get_origin();
}

void Node2D::set_global_position(const Point2 &p_pos) {

    Transform2D inv;
    CanvasItem *pi = get_parent_item();
    if (pi) {
        inv = pi->get_global_transform().affine_inverse();
        set_position(inv.xform(p_pos));
    } else {
        set_position(p_pos);
    }
}
```

This is `set_position`, by the way (notice it writes `pos`):

```
void Node2D::set_position(const Point2 &p_pos) {

    if (_xform_dirty)
        ((Node2D *)this)->_update_xform_values();
    pos = p_pos;
    _update_transform();
    _change_notify("position");
}
```

And `_update_transform` (with conspicuous `!is_inside_tree()` check):

```
void Node2D::_update_transform() {

    _mat.set_rotation_and_scale(angle, _scale);
    _mat.elements[2] = pos;

    VisualServer::get_singleton()->canvas_item_set_transform(get_canvas_item(), _mat);

    if (!is_inside_tree())
        return;

    _notify_transform();
}
```

Notice that `_update_transform` updates `_mat` based on `pos`.

What about `get_global_transform`? Not in that file. We find it in the [source for `CanvasItem`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/3.3/scene/2d/canvas_item.cpp):

```
Transform2D CanvasItem::get_global_transform() const {
#ifdef DEBUG_ENABLED
    ERR_FAIL_COND_V(!is_inside_tree(), get_transform());
#endif
    if (global_invalid) {
        const CanvasItem *pi = get_parent_item();
        if (pi) {
            global_transform = pi->get_global_transform() * get_transform();
        } else {
            global_transform = get_transform();
        }

        global_invalid = false;
    }

    return global_transform;
}
```

And there is the failed assert you saw: `!is_inside_tree()`.

Oh, about that `global_invalid`. If you search for it on the source, you will find it is set to true when the node exits the scene tree or the transform is modified (that is in `_notify_transform`, which I'm not including here, but you can see it is called by `_update_transform` when it is in the scene tree).

What can we make out of all this?

1. The property `global_position` is simply syntactic sugar for the methods `get_global_position` and `set_global_position`.
2. The methods `get_global_position` and `set_global_position` work on the global transform, which is inherited from CanvasItem.
3. To figure out the global position, we need to work out the transforms on the parent nodes. *Which means, we could also figure it out by going over the same process, and thus these methods technically not necessary.*
4. It is done lazily. The global position gets invalidated, and it is recomputed on demand.
5. If the node is not in the scene tree… What parent nodes? In this case using `global_position` would be doing the same if we were using `position`. *Thus, we could say `global_position` is not useful when the node is not in the scene tree.*
6. There is an assert that tells you when you are using it and it is not in the scene tree. And that assert gave you the message you posted.