# Is "variable dot property" construct (var.property) just syntaxic sugar for accessors?

Tags: properties, accessor, godot, gdscript

This is a follow up question to this one: [Are accessors of class properties useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67325426/6537892)

In this [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67325868/6537892) it is stated that:

"*When you use the property, you are using the getter and setter methdods. The property is a convenience for language binding. Thus, we could also say that you don't need the property, only the getter and setter.*"

---

But the following experiment seems to contradict that point:

#### file `src/PositiveInteger.gd`

With a setter which prevents negative integer to be assigned to the property `n`

```
class_name PositiveInteger

var n: int 

func _init() -> void:
    self.n = 0
    
func set_n(_n: int) -> void:
    if _n < 0:
        n = 0
    else:
        n = _n

func get_n() -> int:
    return n
```

---

#### file `main.gd`

Now let us consider this test, with `c1` using the setter and `c2` using the dot construct:

```
tool

extends EditorScript
tool

extends EditorScript

func _run() -> void:
    var PositiveInteger = load("res://src/PositiveInteger.gd")
    var c1 = PositiveInteger.new()
    c1.set_n(-3)
    print("c1: " + str(c1.n))
    var c2 = PositiveInteger.new()
    c2.n = -3
    print("c2: " + str(c2.n))
```

---

#### The output is:

```
c1: 0
c2: -3
```

So the property assignement seems to bypass the setter, is this behaviour different with the core class of the language only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My prior answer applies to core classes (and should apply to modules classes), which are written in C++. They do not expose anything by default. Instead they must bind their C++ methods as methods and properties to expose them.

Now, if you want something like that for a class created in GDScript, you can do it with [`setget`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#setters-getters):

```
class_name PositiveInteger

var n: int setget set_n, get_n

func _init() -> void:
    self.n = 0
    
func set_n(_n: int) -> void:
    if _n < 0:
        n = 0
    else:
        n = _n

func get_n() -> int:
    return n
```

With that your output should be:

```
0
0
```